# Unable to install sftp package in python on my virtual machine

Tags: python, pip, pysftp, pep517

I need to use sftp services through python on my virtual machine.
To note that I am unable to do commands like

`pip install packagename`

I have limitations on the controlled VM. So I have to download packages and point to local disk locations (`pip install C:/Folder/packacgename.whl`) to install them so please give me suggestions keeping this in mind.

Trying to install
`pip install C:\Windows\pysftp-0.2.9.tar.gz` 
I needed bycrypt. And trying to install that it said No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0

I downloaded setuptools and did
`pip install C:\Windows\setuptools-59.2.0.tar.gz`

I get message
Missing build time requirements in pyproject.toml for file:///C:/Windows/setuptools-59.2.0.tar.gz: 'setuptools' and 'wheel'.
This version of pip does not implement PEP 517 so it cannot build a wheel without 'setuptools' and 'wheel'.
Installing build dependencies ... error
Complete output from command z:\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jmi2p:
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

I tried doing
`C:\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`   
This failed with message pip already up to date

I checked pip version
`pip --version`
pip 10.0.1 from z:\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Manually trying to upgrade pip with tar file I get message setup tools need upgrade
`pip install --upgrade C:\Windows\pip-21.3.1.tar.gz`

I used --no-binary :all: , this didn’t work.
I have downloaded Microsoft 2015 build tools and installed them as advised by some forum. It didn’t work. I don't really know how to fix this issue. Trying to download PEP517 tar file and installing that does not work as it wants pip to be upgraded. It's like I am going in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use paramiko package for connecting your sftp via Python.
You just have to do

```
pip install paramiko
```

Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: I am trying this out now. Fingers crossed. I'll update if it works

Comment: This worked just fine. I'll have to figure out how to use it now. Thanks much